# weird error in arrow function with comma operator

Tags: javascript

```
const bifurcate = (arr, filter) =>
  arr.reduce((acc, val, i) => (acc[filter[i] ? 0 : 1].push(val), acc), [[], []]);
  const r = bifurcate(['beep', 'boop', 'foo', 'bar'], [true, true, false, true]);
  console.log(r); // [ [ 'beep', 'boop', 'bar' ], [ 'foo' ] ]
```

I was trying to understand how the code works.
What I did first was trying to use console.log in the callback of reduce function to see what values are there. But I failed because I cannot put `console.log` in the function

```
// FAILURE CODE
const bifurcate = (arr, filter) =>
  arr.reduce((acc, val, i) => {
    return (acc[filter[i] ? 0 : 1].push(val), acc), [[], []];
});
```

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
ERROR : TypeError: acc[(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)].push is not a function at arr.reduce (C:\Users\1nept\project\Connector\test.js:19:36)
```

As what I know, if there is no curly brackets in the arrow function, the return value is the result of expression right after the arrow.
So, the upper reduce codes are same.

But suprisingly, the bottom one cause error.
I don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass two arguments to `Array.prototype.reduce`:

```
const bifurcate = (arr, filter) => arr.reduce(
    // first argument
    (acc, val, i) => (acc[filter[i] ? 0 : 1].push(val), acc),
    // second argument
    [[], []]
);
```

The proper versions with curly braces would thus be:

```
const bifurcate = (arr, filter) => arr.reduce(
    // first argument
    (acc, val, i) => {
        acc[filter[i] ? 0 : 1].push(val);
        return acc;
    },
    // second argument
    [[], []]
);
```